# Validation step being verbose

Tags: keras

I'm building an image classifier.

Had the output metrics that I wanted.

I added an ImageDataGenerator and the validation step added its own output metrics in the middle of the main output. Like So:

```
Epoch 58/300
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 65us/sample - loss: 0.7600 - acc: 0.8301
 - 15s - loss: 0.5111 - acc: 0.9054 - val_loss: 0.7654 - val_acc: 0.8301
```

Here's the model compiler:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer= SGD(
        lr= 0.0,
        momentum= hp['momentum'],
        nesterov= True,
        ),
    loss= categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics= ['accuracy'],
    )
```

Here's the ImageDataGenerator:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    width_shift_range=4,
    height_shift_range=4,
    fill_mode= 'constant',
    cval = 0.0,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    )
```

Here's the fit function call **before** adding the generator:

```
model.fit(
    x= train_data,
    y= train_labels,
    epochs= hp['num_epoch'],
    verbose= 2,
    callbacks= [lr_scheduler],
    validation_data= (
        valid_data, valid_labels
        ),
    )

Epoch 8/300
- 21s - loss: 0.8771 - acc: 0.8077 - val_loss: 1.1955 - val_acc: 0.7258
```

And **after** the generator:

```
model.fit_generator(
    datagen.flow(
        train_data, train_labels,
        batch_size= hp['batch_size'],
        ),
    epochs= hp['num_epoch'],
    verbose= 2,
    callbacks= [lr_scheduler],
    validation_data= (
        valid_data, valid_labels),
    )

Epoch 58/300
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 65us/sample - loss: 0.7600 - acc: 0.8301
 - 15s - loss: 0.5111 - acc: 0.9054 - val_loss: 0.7654 - val_acc: 0.8301
```

Is this a known bug? Should I submit a bug report? Did I make a Stupid? Is there (hopefully) an easy solution?

Thanks, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, this is not a known bug, you should add a complete code example that reproduces the problem. I have never seen such thing.

Comment: I've got it running multiple full training sessions to get dependable data on it's performance. That will run for several hours yet. When it's done though I'll see what the simplest reproduction I can make is. I do think it's just adding the data generator though.

Comment: Also, by way of update. It still happens if the validation data is served by `ImageDataGenerator` and also when `verbose= 0`

Comment: I use ImageDataGenerator regularly and I don't see this at all, make sure its not some artifact of a queueing system or other non-keras code. Also, which version of Keras are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

I updated from TF 1.13.0 to TF 1.14.0 And it cleared up.

Apparently TensorFlow or Keras found this bug already.